# Qt5 Osx Linker Error

Tags: linker, qt5, libs

I am receiving the following error after this linker command from qmake generated Makefile.

```
clang++ -headerpad_max_install_names -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -o bin/Clock tmp/clock.o tmp/config.o tmp/main.o tmp/qrc_resources.o tmp/moc_clock.o   -L/Users/foo/Qt5.0.0/5.0.0/clang_64/lib -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -framework OpenGL -framework AGL
```

error:

```
ld: library not found for -lQt5Widgets
```

I can confirm that the library is not there with that spelling.
However there is a QtWidgets.la as well there is a QtWidgets.framework dir that has a QtWidgets.

In the lib directory none of the files have a Qt5 prefix is there some way of changing Qt so it does not look for it etc.

I understand that I could rename things and move them around but this is a big job remaining all libs to have a Qt5 prefix.